# Проблема с миграцией базы данных на postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

При создании базы возникает следующая ошибка:

```
andrey@asus:~/project/odnogrupniki$ rake db:create:all
FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "odnogrupniki"
```

логи целиком: [ТУТ](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/15526466/)

databse.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter:  postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: 'odnogrupniki'
  password: '1111'

development:
  <<: *default
  database: odnogrupniki

test:
  <<: *default
  database: odnogrupniki_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: odnogrupniki_production
```

в Gemfile добавлял: `gem 'pg'`

 `Bundle` - выполнял

```
andrey@asus:~/project/odnogrupniki$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.5.1
```

Пользователя создавал так:

```
postgres@asus:/home/andrey/project/odnogrupniki$ createuser odnogrupniki -P -S -R -D
Enter password for new role: 
Enter it again:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Локально можно настроиться на работу по **peer athentication**, но для этого в базе данных должен быть пользователь с таким же именем, какой у подключающегося **логин в операционной системе**. Для разработки это можно настроить максимально быстро на чистом дистрибутиве.

Чтобы ActiveRecord подключался, удостоверяясь только с помощью учётной записи подключающегося через *Unix domain socket*, то надо **убрать логин, пароль и хост из настроек подключения**. *Совсем.* А сделать "себя" суперпользователем в БД на свежеустановленном PostgreSQL (когда пользователь там всего один, `postgres`) можно в одну команду:

```
sudo -u postgres createuser --superuser $(whoami)
```

```
\______________/ \______________________________/
  Притворившись    Создать суперпользователя с
   postgres      именем, выведенным командой whoami
```

А дальше обычное `rake db:create` и прочее.

Плюсов у такого подхода хватает:

- Работает с настройками по умолчанию: установил, сделал себя-администратора и вперёд
- Учётные данные ни в какой момент не существуют в рабочем дереве

На "боевом" сервере так делать не стоит, но это уже *совсем другая история...*

Answer (score 1):

Замените в конфигурационном файле pg_hba.conf метод аутентификации, вместо аутентификации по системным учетным записям

```
local all postgres peer
```

укажите аутентификацию по паролю

```
local all postgres md5
```

Comment: или на trust для локальной базы