# Ошибка FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "maxprof"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь подключится к БД postgresql, но выскакивает ошибка FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "maxprof";

Сайт добавлял командой 'rails new myapp --database=postgresql'

До этого создал пользователя 'maxprof'

В файле /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf заменил строчку на:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             maxprof                                md5
```

Код файла database.yml

```
  default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: 5

development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: myapp_development
  pool: 5
  username: maxprof
  password: 544752

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: myapp_test
  pool: 5
  username: maxprof
  password: 544752


production:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_production
  username: myapp
  password: <%= ENV['MYAPP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Comment: См. также: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/507215/181100

Comment: @D-side Спасибо!)

Comment: ...я не был уверен, дубликат ли это и не стал закрывать. С одной стороны, это однозначно решит проблему на машине разработчика, с другой, там совершенно не рассказано, что делать в продакшене, а об этом рассказывать я не готов. Но если ответы оттуда решают вашу проблему, то этот вопрос надо б закрывать.

Comment: То есть просто удалить вопрос? Кнопочки "закрыть" не вижу)

Comment: "Удаление молча", насколько я знаю, на SE не уважают и за серийное удаление собственных вопросов можно потерять возможность их задавать вообще. Я повесил голос на "дубликат", вроде авторы могут их поддержать решающим голосом. Я вопросов (почти) не задаю и не знаю интерфейсов "по ту сторону" .-.