# rails как подключить базу PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Есть готовое приложение с sqlite3 перенос данных не предусматривается.
Нужно подключить PostgreSQL, создать новую базу и сделать миграции.
PostgreSQL установил.
Создал пользователя

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql
postgres-# CREATE ROLE pguser LOGIN ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'passwd' NOSUPERUSER NOINHERIT CREATEDB NOCREATEROLE;
```

Смотрю в pgAdmin

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Иду в database.yml

```
development:
pool: 5
timeout: 5000
adapter: postgresql
database: newdb
username: pguser
password: passwd
```

Естественно гем pg стоит.

Запускаю db:create или db:setup

```
$ rake db:setup
FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "pguser"
Couldn't create database for {...}
```

Добавил pg_hba.conf

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что в pg_hba.conf? В этом конфиге описывается, какие пользователи откуда могут подключаться и с каким методом аутентификации. Судя по "Peer authentication failed" postgresql пытается использовать аутентификацию peer, т.е. клиент должен быть авторизован в ОС под этим логином. А пользователя у вас такого, скорей всего, нет вовсе.

Comment: @Мелкий Добавил конфиг. Поменял local all all peer => md5 заработало, спасибо.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проблема с миграцией базы данных на postgres](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/507215/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bd%d0%b0-postgres)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кроме создания пользователя в PosqtgreSQL, зачастую необходимо проверить [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) и изменить при необходимости. В этом конфиге описывается, какие пользователи откуда могут подключаться и каким методом аутентификации должны подключения проверяться.

Судя по "Peer authentication failed" postgresql пытается использовать аутентификацию peer, т.е. клиент должен быть авторизован в ОС под этим логином. А пользователя у вас такого, скорей всего, нет вовсе. Для аутентификации по паролю обычно используется метод `md5`.